# If I have Postgres streaming replication on, do I still need to archive my WAL files?

Tags: postgresql, database-backup

I have set up two servers running Postgres 9.1, with one configured as a hot standby for the other using streaming replication. Given that, is there any reason for me to be archiving my WAL files?

I'm aware that the archived WAL files allow me to "go back in time" to a previous snapshot of the database, but for my particular application, I have no need for such a feature as long as my standby is ok. Are there any other reasons to keep them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the only reason you're keeping the WAL files is for replication and not backup, then no, you don't need to keep them once they've been fully incorporated into the secondary server. My understanding is that [`archive_cleanup_command`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/archive-recovery-settings.html#ARCHIVE-CLEANUP-COMMAND) should be handling this.